# Finding the Hessian of $\sqrt{1+|x|^2}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{1+|x|^2}$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I found that $\nabla f(x) = \frac{1}{2}(1+|x|^2)^{-1/2}(2x)$, but is there an easy way to compute the Hessian?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In index notation with summation convention,
$$ \partial_i \sqrt{1+x_kx_k} = \frac{2x_k \delta_{ik}}{2\sqrt{1+x_lx_l}} = \frac{x_i}{\sqrt{1+x_kx_k}}. $$
Differentiating again,
$$ \partial_j\partial_i \sqrt{1+x_kx_k} = \frac{\delta_{ij}}{\sqrt{1+x_kx_k}} - \frac{x_i x_j }{(1+x_kx_k)^{3/2}} = \frac{(1+\lvert x \rvert^2)\delta_{ij}-x_ix_j}{(1+\lvert x \rvert^2)^{3/2}}. $$
If you really want, this can be written as the matrix $ (1+\lvert x \rvert^2)^{-3/2}((1+\lvert x \rvert^2)I + xx^T)  $.